# mongoosesastic no living connection

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I'm trying to insert my mongoose scheme into elasticsearch with mongoosastic
but it gives me
`{ [Error: No Living connections] message: 'No Living connections' }`

my mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
var ProductSchema = new Schema( {
   ----huge load of json----
});

ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic,{host:'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200',curlDebug: true});

mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema);

var product = mongoose.model('product');
product.createMapping(function(err, mapping){
if(err){
    console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
    console.log(err);
}else{
    console.log('mapping created!');
    console.log(mapping);
}
});
module.exports = product;
```

I can curl to the elasticsearch server, so no issue there

Comment: No living connections usually mean that your code cannot reach your ES server. Have you tried to restart your ES server by any chance?

Comment: yes I tried, no success :(

Comment: Are you sure you instantiated your plugin correctly? Shouldn't you create an elasticsearch client first, like this? `var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({host: 'localhost:9200'});
productSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  esClient: esClient
})`

Comment: Also what do you see when you run this in a shell `curl -XGET http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200` ? (make sure to use the correct host or IP address)

Comment: @Val You are right. after creating the client i got  `[TypeError: Invalid index: expected be a comma seperated list, array, number or string.]` 'instead of the no living connections error :) *it's something*

Comment: @Val curl output is
   `{
      "status" : 200,
      "name" : "Madelyne Pryor",
       "cluster_name" : "thiscluster",
      "version" : {
        "number" : "1.5.2",
        "build_hash" : "62ff9868b4c8a0c45860bebb259e21980778ab1c",
        "build_timestamp" : "2015-04-27T09:21:06Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by passing my ip in an array

```
ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic,{
hosts: [
    'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200'
 ]
});
```

must be a bug in mongoosastic

Comment: I was using the configuration in the require call, (require('mongoosastic', {..config}) and doesn't work. I changed to each plugin call like you say and worked fine. Thanks