# Mongoosastic - { [Error: No Living connections] message: 'No Living connections' }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Im trying to use mongoosastic for searching purposes, but I keep getting 'No Living connections' error and mapping problem

Here's the code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var JobSchema = Schema({
  category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', es_indexed:true},
  title: { type: String, es_indexed:true },

});

JobSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema);
```

routes.js

```
var Job = require('../models/job');

Job.createMapping(function(err, mapping) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('mapping created!');
    console.log(mapping);
  }
});

app.post('/search', function(req, res, next) {
    Job.search({query_string: {query: req.body.q}}, function(err, results) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

I keep getting this error,

[image]

Can anyone with experience in using mongoosastic tell,me how do i fix this problem?

Comment: Might be stupid question, but is your elasticsearch service running?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Do i need to run it?

Comment: Well, mongoosastic is supposed to index it to Elasticsearch as per my understanding. So you have to install it, run as a service and configure your code to connect to it. At least that's how I understand it works looking at documentation.

Comment: @JackMoscovi see my answer how to start service and how to configure Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

When adding the plugin to your `JobSchema` model, you need to pass a second parameter with how to connect to Elasticsearch:

```
JobSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  hosts: [
    'localhost:9200'
  ]
});
```

You can also re-use an Elasticsearch client object if you have one ready.

```
var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({host: 'localhost:9200'});
JobSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  esClient: esClient
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same issue but I solved now using below method

> **Its very simple :** you have to install elastic search in your local or anywhere else

1. **Download elastic search**  http://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch
2. **Extract** folder
3. go to folder from cmd or Treminal find bin folder and inside that folder run **elastic search** script
4. And in **nodejs** code by default it will link to **localhost:9200** so no need to use 
   **new elasticsearch.Client({host: 'localhost:9200'})** , but if your elastic search deloyed some where else then you have to use above **client method**

Comment: Install with homebrew: "brew install elasticsearch". Open new tab to execute the elasticsearch server, cmd: "elasticsearch"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a client and pass it into the plugin, but use ip addresses that is what worked for me.

```
// http://127.0.0.1:9200 == http://localhost:9200

var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({host: 'http://127.0.0.1:9200'});
JobSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: esClient
})
```

Note: if you were not previously using elasticsearch you might have to re-index your documents (I had to, but I may have done something wrong)

Referencing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30204512/1146562

from that answer you can pass host straight into the plugin and do not have to create the client.