# Search in mongoosastic doesn't give any result

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I tried to use mongoosastic search but it doesnt work

Job.js (Mongoose schema)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var JobSchema = Schema({
  title: { type: String, es_indexed:true },
  category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', es_indexed:true},
  salary: { type: String, es_indexed:true },
});


JobSchema.plugin(timestamps);
JobSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  hosts: [
    'localhost:9200'
  ]});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema);
```

Routes.js

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();       
var Job = require('../models/job');


Job.createMapping(function(err, mapping) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('mapping created!');
    console.log(mapping);
  }
});


app.post('/api/search/', function(req, res, next) {
  Job.search({query_string: {query: req.body.test}}, function(err, results) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

This is the data sets that already been saved in mongodb

```
    {
     "id": 12313,
     "title": "Engineer"
    },
    {
     "id": 13123,
     "title": "Doctor"  
    },
    {
     "id": 121243134,
     "title": "Software Engineer"
    }
```

When I tried to run the search and search like "Engineer" and I keep getting this result.

[image]

Updated for Curl

curl -XGET localhost:9200/_mapping

[image]

curl -XGET localhost:9200/_search

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `title` is an analyzed String, its value is indexed using the standard analyzer, i.e. in lowercased form, so "Engineer" will be indexed and "engineer"

Try searching for "engineer" in lowercase instead.

**UPDATE**

Based on our discussion, it seems that the problem is simply that your Elasticsearch is empty. Since you have existing data in MongoDB, you need to make sure to [call the `synchronize()`](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#indexing-an-existing-collection) method on your model in order to index all your MongoDB collection inside Elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping type that was created using `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_mapping` ? Also if you can ensure that something is at all present in Elasticsearch using `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_search`

Comment: Your screenshots don't show the full thing. It's also better to paste real code than screenshot as it facilitates searching later on. Also it doesn't look like the schema you're showing in your question is the real one being used, since the real one seems to have more fields.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to show everything is because I don't want to complicate things.

Comment: What do you want me to do now?

Comment: I added all the fields. that are needed.

Comment: No worries. I understand. What do you see in the second query for `hits.total`? Also how do you make the request to `/api/search`?

Comment: There you go, if a search for anything (i.e. `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_search`) yields 0 results, it means your ES doesn't contain anything and nothing was indexed from MongoDB.

Comment: and this is the message, after mapping `{ acknowledged: true }`

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean data was indexed. Creating a mapping and indexing data are two different operations that can be done at different times. You need to [index data](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#indexing) first.

Comment: I already added `es_indexed: true` if you check my code above

Comment: `es_indexed` only tells that you want to store that specific field in ES, but nothing gets indexed at that time.

Comment: How do I indexed it, since in the documentation, it doesnt show anything.

Comment: See the link I posted in my earlier comment: https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#indexing

Comment: this one only shows when saving a document to database and use es-indexed and another one is indexing to elastic search which I already did.

Comment: Your ES seems to be empty though, so something must have happened during your indexing. Maybe is it related to your other question where you had [no Living connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869013/mongoosastic-error-no-living-connections-message-no-living-connections)?

Comment: I already solved that living connection, I didnt run elasticsearch command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96001/discussion-between-val-and-jack-moscovi).

Comment: If you are busy I will get it back to you later.

Comment: I'm in there, waiting for your response :)

Comment: Hey, Im really sorry I was out just now, when are you free?

Comment: I have a new question, if you could answer it would be good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913617/how-to-do-instant-search-with-mongoosastic

Comment: Hey guys, it seems like you have got the solution specifically on how to index existing data from mongodb to es then i am wondering what was the real problem since i am here trying to use synchronize to index existing docs but nothing works, Es continue to be empty after synchronize operation get completed? Can anyone help....