# How to stop duplication on instant search? jquery + AJAX + mongoosastic

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongoosastic

Currently The instant search that I'm using is working perfectly but , there is only one problem.

Whenever I type "Chemical",  it will show the query for

```
Chemical Engineer
Chemical Entrepreneur
Checmical People
```

But let say I decided to add "Engineer" after "Chemical", then the result will be

```
Chemical Engineer
Chemical Entrepreneur
Checmical People
Chemical Engineer
Chemical Entrepreneur
Checmical People
```

Here's the code

router.js

```
router.post('/api/search/', function(req, res, next) {

  Product.search(
    {
      query_string:
      { query: req.body.search_term }
    } , function(err, results) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

custom.js

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    // 1. grab the search term from the input field
    var search_term = $(this).val();

    // 2. send it to your back-end via ajax in the body
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/api/search",            // <-- your back-end endpoint
      data: { search_term },  // <-- what you're sending
      dataType: "json",              // <-- what you're expecting back
      success: function(json){       // <-- do something with the JSON you get
        // 3. parse the JSON and display the results
        var res = json.hits.hits.map(function(hit) {
          return hit;
        });
        console.log(res);
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          $('.testing').append('<li>' + res[i]._source.name + '</li>');
        }

      },
      error: function(data){
        alert('Error', data);
      }
    });
  });
```

How do i stop duplication?

after using curl -XGET localhost:9200/products/_mapping suggested by Val

```
{"products":{"mappings":{"product":{"properties":{"_id":{"type":"string"},"category":{"type":"string"},"description":{"type":"string"},"image":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"price":{"type":"double"},"sizes":{"type":"string"},"stocks":{"type":"double"}}}}}}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping type you have in your index? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/products/_mapping`. Also what do you get when querying ES directly with this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/products/_search?q=Chemical%20Engineer&pretty`

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are appending results to `testing`  container without clearing it. Try to do `$('.testing').html('')` before running `for` loop in `success` callback.

Comment: Did you try a `$('.testing').empty()` before `for` loop I think cleaning old `<li>` could work

Comment: @Val just want to clarify something, the problem is not with elastic search itself, but rather the ajax calling, because everytime I type something, it will keep triggering the ajax call, and do the Product.search over and over again

Comment: The code you have is not the one I had in my answer, which was `$('search_results').html(res.join("<br />"));` and did indeed replace the whole HTML on every response. You have probably used the code from the other answer, which uses `append`.

Comment: is not this a duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay` ?

Comment: Use the right code from [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33962886/4604579) and you'll not see any duplication. It seems you've mixed and matched both answers and you took the wrong bits ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should clean previus results.
Always you press a key you get the value of textfield and that value will be sent through ajax. 
If you write `Chemical` you will get some responses which will be appended to your html, all those responses matched with `Chemical` so when you write `Chemical Engineering` you need to clean up previus appended tags  so I think this could be enough:

`custom.js`

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    // 1. grab the search term from the input field
    var search_term = $(this).val();

    // 2. send it to your back-end via ajax in the body
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/api/search",            // <-- your back-end endpoint
      data: { search_term },  // <-- what you're sending
      dataType: "json",              // <-- what you're expecting back
      success: function(json){       // <-- do something with the JSON you get
        // 3. parse the JSON and display the results
        var res = json.hits.hits.map(function(hit) {
          return hit;
        });
        console.log(res);
        $('.testing').empty(); ///new line added
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          $('.testing').append('<li>' + res[i]._source.name + '</li>');
        }

      },
      error: function(data){
        alert('Error', data);
      }
    });
  });
```

PS: The sentence `var search_term = $(this).val();` is not necessary `keyup` function gives you through parameter the `event` with the `element`

https://api.jquery.com/keyup/