# How to solve AccessDeniedException in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Currently I have two accounts on mac, one is the original and the other one is the newly created both are admin type

```
Original account name is  = Jack

Newly created is = Snooke
```

In Jack account when I type in `elasticsearch` on the terminal its working fine

But when i type `elasticsearch` on Snooke's terminal I received this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to created node environment
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_jack/nodes/1
```

It seems like Snooke is trying to access Jack's elastic search folder?

How do I solve this?

Comment: You've probably installed Elasticsearch in a shared location as user Jack and now trying to use it as user Snooke. You probably need to run elasticsearch with another data folder specifically for user Snooke. Another way is to chmod the folder so that user Snooke can access it.

Comment: Can you show me the solution?

Comment: @Val can you show me the solution so I could accept it as an answer?

Comment: Can you show the current value of the `path.data` property in your `config/elasticsearch.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Mac users with admin rights are in the group staff. Problem is that elasticsearch writes folders in the data folder with the rights **r-x**. So other members of the group do not have write access to these folders. You could change these access rights for all the folders by doing some like chmod -R 775. But I think that with every new folder that is created you would face the same problems.

This problem is only there if you want keep using the data with both accounts. If you just want to use the new account you could go to the elasticsearch folder and do: (Notice the '.' at the end)

```
chown -R Snooke:staff .
```